# Yealink & Aruba 1930 Switch Connection Issues

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet, aruba, eee

Good day,

I have connectivity issues on my network.

I recently installed new Aruba Instant On 1930 switches with POE and SFP+.

After the new install I started having connectivity issues to my Yealink T33G IP Phones.

The phone gives a No Network error every couple of minutes. The phone never dies so the POE is doing its job, however the connection keeps dropping.

I do however know that when I connect the phone to another smaller 8 port Aruba POE switch there is no issues what so ever, but the moment I connect it to the main 1930 switch it gets those connection issues.

What I did up until now: Checked that both the switch and the phone has the latest Firmware. I replaced the phone with another. I replaced the cables coming from the RJ45 Keystone to the phone. I replaced the RJ45 Keystone on the user side and on the patch panel. I replaced the cable from the patch panel to the users network point. I replaced the patch cord between the switch and the patch panel. I have even removed the Vlan config and disabled the LLDP for the sake of it.

None of this worked.

We also use Snom which works perfectly fine, but the Yealinks does not want to function correctly.

This is the running config of the switch with my IP addresses and certificates and so removed for security purposes:

```
config-file-header
SW0003
vInstantOn_1930_2.8.0.0 (17) / RHPE2.8_932_244_010
SKU Description "Aruba Instant On 1930 24G Class4 PoE 4SFP/SFP+ 195W
Switch JL683B"
@
!
unit-type-control-start 
unit-type unit 1 network gi uplink te 
unit-type-control-end 
!
vlan database
vlan 10-101,20-201 
exit
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 3Com
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 H3C
voice vlan oui-table add 64167f Polycom
voice vlan oui-table add 805e0c Yealink
priority-queue out num-of-queues 0 
hostname SW0003
username XXX password encrypted 
snmp-server server
snmp-server engineid local default 
snmp-server location M
snmp-server community XXX ro XXX view Default 
management vlan 101 
!
interface vlan 10
 name LAN 
!
interface vlan 101
 name LAN-B 
 ip address XXX 
 no ip address dhcp 
!
interface vlan 20
 name SIP 
!
interface vlan 201
 name "Guest" 
!
interface 1
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 2
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 3
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 4
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 5
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 6
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 7
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 8
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 9
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 10
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 11
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 12
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 13
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 14
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 15
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 16
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 17
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 18
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 19
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
 no lldp transmit 
 no lldp receive 
 lldp notifications disable 
 lldp optional-tlv port-desc sys-name sys-desc sys-cap
 lldp m disable 
 lldp management-address none 
!
interface 20
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 21
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 22
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 23
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 24
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10-101,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 25
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10-101,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 26
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10-101,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 27
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10-101,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface 28
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10-101,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK1
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK2
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK3
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK4
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK5
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK6
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK7
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface TRK8
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,20-201 tagged 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
exit
ip default-gateway XXX 
ip ssh-client key rsa key-pair
```

The switch log shows link down and a couple of seconds later link up. It does this the whole day every couple of minutes.

Is there anyone with a solution ?

Comment: Please add the switch configuration to your question, in text format, using the editor's `{}` preformat option. Also, what does the switch log show?

Comment: Yes, switch logs will indicate if the link is actually dropping. You may need to configure the switch to log interface state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution.

Being that the Aruba switches are relatively new, they have the latest features included. One of them is EEE (Energy Efficient Ethernet).

In my case The Snom Phones are a little outdated and do not support EEE, However, the newer Yealink phones do support EEE. I went through all my switches and found that on each and every port where there is a Yealink connected the link drops. It turns out that there are known issues regarding the negotiation with EEE and this can cause occasional dropouts.

I turned off the feature on my switches, and so far so good. The logs are clearing up. It has only been a few hours, but it looks good now.

Answer (score 1):

> The switch log shows link down and a couple of seconds later link up. It does this the whole day every couple of minutes.

If the *physical link* goes up and down, the problem is either

- switch port
- cable
- device/device port

Since you only experience this problem with a specific kind of phone, the problem seems to be the phone type interacting with the 1930. My general guess is that either LLDP or spanning tree BPDUs (seems not active though) cause problems with the phone, crashing it and the reboot causing the port to flap. You could examine (crash) logs from the phone, but end devices are off topic here.

I would run a packet capture on such a port. Most likely, just before the port goes down, some kind of frame is transmitted, causing the crash (if my theory fits). Possibly, more than one frame of that type is required to crash the phone (as it takes several minutes). Additionally, a comparative capture from another switch may be helpful.

Once you've got the frame content, either eliminate it or get the manufacturer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We were running into the same issue and, upon checking the switch configuration, we realized the EEE energy saving option was on.  Turned it off and the phones stopped disconnecting.  We spent months trying to figure out what the problem was.